# Deserialize JSON with Association using JMSSerializer

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

In my project, I need to update Doctrine2 entities with JMSSerializer. My JSON looks like this:

```
{"id":28,"prefixes":[{"id":8},{"id":11},{"id":14}]}
```

My entity defines `prefixes` as a ManyToMany association. I'm already using the Doctrine Object Constructor.

When I attempt to deserialize the JSON, JMSSerializer deserializes the `prefixes` as new entities, which results in this error:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'PartKeepr\\UnitBundle\\Entity\\Unit#prefixes' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity
```

Any light on what's going on?

Comment: Have You tried adding "cascade: persist" on this relations definition in your Unit entity schema file?

Answer (score 0):

The question is obsolete, as the issue occured because I had two entity managers in place: One legacy and one from doctrine.